# Como decorar un arbol de navidad en javascript

Tags: javascript

Quisiera que mi árbol de navidad tuviera adornos aleatorios, pero cada vez que reemplazo el string este reemplaza el primer * que encuentra en el string.

Output

```
      *      
     ***     
    *****    
   ooo****   
  *********  
 o********** 
o************
      #
```

```js
const getRandomDecorators = (max) => { return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) }

function treeGenerator(size){
    var arr = []
    const decoratorCounter = 10

    // Create asterix tree
    for(var i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        var space = Array(size - i + 1).join(' ')
        arr.push(space + Array(2 * i).join('*') + space)
        if(i==size){
            var space2 = Array(size).join(' ')
            arr.push(space2 + Array(2).join('#') + space2)
        }
    }

    // Add tree decorators in random places
    for(i = 0; i < decoratorCounter; i++){
      var randomDecorator = getRandomDecorators(arr.length)
      arr[randomDecorator] = arr[randomDecorator].replace('*', 'o')
    }

    return arr.join('\n')
}

console.log(treeGenerator(7))
```

Output esperado:

```
      *      
     ***     
    **o**    
   o******   
  ******o**  
 o***o**o*** 
o***o*****o**
      #
```

Answer (score 3):

Aqui te dejo una posible solucion

```
function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substring(0,index) + chr + str.substring(index+1);
}

const getRandomDecorators = (max) => { return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) }

function treeGenerator(size){
    var arr = []
    const decoratorCounter = 10

    // Create asterix tree
    for(var i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        var space = Array(size - i + 1).join(' ')
        arr.push(space + Array(2 * i).join('*') + space)
        if(i==size){
            var space2 = Array(size).join(' ')
            arr.push(space2 + Array(2).join('#') + space2)
        }
    }

    // Add tree decorators in random places
    for(i = 0; i < decoratorCounter; i++){
      var randomDecorator = getRandomDecorators(arr.length)
      var temp = arr[randomDecorator]
      var randomReplace = getRandomDecorators(temp.length)
      if(temp.charAt(randomReplace) == '*'){
        arr[randomDecorator] = setCharAt(temp,randomReplace,'O')
      }
    }

    return arr.join('\n')
}

console.log(treeGenerator(9))
```

resultado:

```
        O        
       ***       
      *****      
     *******     
    *O*******    
   *******O***   
  *************  
 *O***********O* 
*******O*********
        #
```

Digo posible por que le falta optimizar ya que en algunas corridas solo pone pocos adornos.

La funcion para el replace aleatorio la tome de aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript

```
function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substring(0,index) + chr + str.substring(index+1);
}
```

Comment: Un muy buen resultado!, además si agrega la variable minDecoratorCounter y maxDecoratorCounter se puede determinar un rango de adornos de manera completamente random

Answer (score 2):

Cambie un poco la lógica de tu código, el árbol es un array, que tiene otro array dentro, este último array siempre tiene 2 elementos
0: un string con los espacios
1: otro array con un carácter

Básicamente lo siguiente:

```
let arbol=[
[ "        ", ['*']]
[ "  "  , ['*','*','*']]
//así sucesivamente
];
```

De esta manera es fácil modificar un elemento cualquiera, y para juntar todo es solamente hace un map

Y si nos olvidamos de los espacios, lo que nos queda es una matriz con filas y columnas, entonces solo hay buscar una fila y columna al azar y cambiar `*` por `o`.

```js
const getRandomDecorators = (max) => { return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) }

function treeGenerator(size) {
    let arr = [];
    const decoratorCounter = 10;

    //creamos el árbol
    for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        arr.push(getFila(i, size, "*"));
    }
    
    //agregamos el tronco
    arr.push(getFila(1, size, "#"));

    //recorremos agregando adornos
    //notar que el i++ esta dentro de un if, así obligamos a encontrar siempre la cantidad deseada de adornos
    for (let i = 0; i < decoratorCounter;) {
        let fila = getRandomDecorators(size); //una fila al azar
        let columna = getRandomDecorators(fila * 2 + 1); //una columna al azar

        if (arr[fila][1][columna] === "*") {
            arr[fila][1][columna] = "o";
            i++; //encontramos adorno, entonces sumamos 1
        }
    }

    //juntamos todo
    return arr.map(a => a[0] + a[1].join("")).join('\n')
}

//Esta función retorna un array con 2 elementos
//0 : un string con los espacios
//1 : otro array con cada letra
function getFila(i, size, char) {
    var space = " ".repeat(size - i + 1);
    return [space, Array.from(char.repeat(2 * i - 1))];
}

console.log(treeGenerator(7))
```